# How to integrate $\int x \cos \frac{1}{x^{2}} $

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I am facing problems regarding integration of the cosine term here...

$$\int x \cos \frac{1}{x^{2}} $$

Comment: looks like a job for substitution. What have you done so far?

Comment: You should expect the result to be non-elementary. Do you know about the "sine integral"?

Comment: @SK19...I've tried using ∫ v du=uv-∫u dv...But to no purpose...

Comment: @mickep...What's sine integral...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint.

$$\frac{1}{x^2} = y ~~~~~~~~~~~ dy = -2y\sqrt{y}\ dx$$

Hence

$$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{y}} \cos(y) \left(-\frac{dy}{2y\sqrt{y}}\right) = -\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{\cos(y)}{y^2}\ dy$$

Then you can do a by parts integration.

**Spoiler**

I hope you studied special function since the final result contains one of them, precisely the so called "Sine Integral". The final solution is:

$$\frac{1}{2}\text{Si}\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)+\frac{1}{2} x^2 \cos \left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$$

Where

$$\text{Si}(x) = \int \frac{\sin(x)}{x}\ dx$$

Comment: and what is the solution?

Comment: +1  @Von Neuman..you can also integrate directly by part ...

Comment: @Isham...I've done that earlier.....I thought that the integral remaining must be solved...But I was confused...

Comment: @Isham That is true too. Probably even easier. I am still fascinated by substitutions, and often I use them even when it's not necessary xD

Comment: well once you integrate it by part directly you still have to substitute like you did to get the sine integral...

Comment: @Isham...In your process,which one should I select as "v" and which one as "du" ?Is there any rule for selection?

Comment: @NehalSamee You always have to select the easiest one. For example if the integral is of the kind $\int x f(x)\ dx$ then $v$ would be $x$ since then $v' = 1$. But it also depends on $f(x)$. There are some functions which are not easily integrable, or unknown. It's all about experience and a bit of intuition.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing Von's point, you may want to consider the series expansion of the integral at x=$\infty$. It will give you more sense of what's happening.

Comment: And then what...?